# How to resume download of a broken/interrupted file in azure blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I would like to implement pause/resume downloading of a file. When the download of a file fails(when suppose network disconnects or due to any other reason) , how can I resume the download from the point of failure? Currently it starts downloading the entire file again in azure. This is being implemented for an iot device . I am fairly new to azure blob and after researching enough ,still unable to find any solution , Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out MS API usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Get-Blob as it talks about partial downloads

Answer (score 0):

The blob item which is stored in Azure Blob Storage has a URI. When you raise a HTTP request on this SAS URI, it accepts a `AddRange` to start again the download from an offset.

So, if the partial file exists, you can recall the HTTP request and give an offset corresponding to the size of the partial file and append the downloaded data to the file in append mode.

Comment: Thank you for the response , could you please provide API details and its usage as a c++ sample code for this explanation( which API to use and how to specify range , how to append the rest of the downloaded data to the partial file) , would be a lot helpful,Thanks in advance